# Code will only accept one user input file instead of the other ones

Tags: c++

I am coding in C++ using Visual Studios and my code will only accept a file called "perm15K.txt". If I try to enter "perm30K.txt" or "sorted15K.txt" my code will not read from it. It does not output an error with file, but it will not let me enter which search I would like to perform.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "binarysearchtree.h"
#include "redblacktree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
struct bstnodes *root = NULL;

std::ifstream in;
std::ofstream out;

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();
std::string test = buffer.str();
std::cout << test << std::endl << std::endl;

ifstream myFile;
string input;
string output;

cout << "Name of the input file? (ie. perm15K.txt)";
getline(cin, input);
myFile.open(input.c_str());

if (myFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error with file\n";
}

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {

        cout << "Which search? Pleast enter bst or redblack\n";

        binarysearchtree temp;
        redblacktree temp1;

        while (!myFile.eof())
        {
            while (getline(myFile, input)) {
                myFile >> input;
                string words = input;

                temp.insert(words);
                temp1.rbinsert(words);
            }       
        }
        getline(cin, input);
            if (input == "bst")
            {
                cout << "\nSearch for what word in the tree\n";
                getline(cin, input);
                temp.insert(input);

                clock_t start_s = clock();
                std::cout << "Match Found: " << temp.search(input) <<     std::endl;
                clock_t stop_s = clock();
                double sum = ((double)(stop_s - start_s));
                cout << endl << "Time: " << sum << " seconds" << endl;

                cout << "\nSearch for what word in the tree\n";
                getline(cin, input);
            }

            if (input == "redblack")
            {
                cout << "\nSearch for what word in the tree\n";
                getline(cin, input);
                temp1.rbinsert(input);
                clock_t start_s = clock();
                temp1.rbsearch(input);
                std::cout << "Match Found: ";                       
                clock_t stop_s = clock();
                double sum = ((double)(stop_s - start_s));
                cout << endl << "Time: " << sum << " seconds" << endl;
                cout << "\nSearch for what word in the tree\n";
                getline(cin, input);
            }

        myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Any help figuring out my problem is greatly appreciated. It is like I am stuck in an endless for loop. I have been trying to find the problem for a couple hours now and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, if the file opening fails `!myFile.eof()` is never false as `myFile.getline()` doesn't behave as expected (infinite loop).

You should return after the error message if the opening fails.

Also, you should just do `while(myFile.getline())`, rather than checking for eof.

Comment: Just remove the `while(!myFile.eof())` line altogether.

Comment: I did that and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: `while (!myFile.eof())` almost never is the right answer. Warned you about this one a few hours ago, @MariaS. Forget this code for a while, and write a simple little program that does nothing but read a file and print it out. If you can't read the file correctly, rest is wasted.

Comment: Good starting example on file reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line

Comment: I agree, first things first!

And given the problems you're facing you should start by adding an else clause to your `if (myFile.fail())` to also report if the file was opened properly.

Comment: [`perror` is also helpful](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror) in diagnosing a file access failure. It often can print out the reason why the file access failed,.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find where Visual Studio is putting your executable and see if the other text files are there.

Also your print statements should be cout << "text" << endl;
If you end them with "\n" you might not actually be flushing the print buffer which could be causing you to lose error output.

Comment: I changed the \n at the end and it made no difference. The text files are in the executable and solution and classes folder.

Comment: When you really care about getting debug message out, use `cerr`, not `cout`.